# why dbml changed relation names of tables?

Tags: linq-to-sql

My problem is that when i drag tables to dbml ,(there are 2 tables ,they have 3 relations with each other that i named these relation in my own pattern) , after drag in dmbl these relation renamed to ralation1 , relation2 , relation3 , and these aren't the truth names.

i need to access to my truth name of relations .

why dbml changes names of relations after map ??

how to do this to don't happen this event??

please help me if any one has idea.

thankes

Comment: you can edit the relation name in the designer

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear in your question if you are renaming the associations in the DBML (through the designer or XML) or in the .Designer file directly. If you modify the .Designer file, any changes you make will be overwritten the next time you change the design surface. If you want changes to be retained, make sure to make the modification in the designer or XML, but not the .Designer file.

If you are doing something else, it might help by providing some steps to reproduce the issue including code.